# How to implement spinners into a list view and still save the item selected from each

Tags: java, android, listview, spinner, android-spinner

So I created a big list of seven spinners that looks like this:

TextView1    Spinner1

TextView2    Spinner2

.... and so one. Each spinner represents a period of the school day and the spinner has a list of classes to choose from. (the list is the same for all periods). After they pick a class from each spinner and click a register button, they have their classes registered. I implemented this just fine but the problem was that I used a scroll view layout so I had to make each spinner and text view in the xml. I want to optimize it and just create a list view instead.

I've already got some of it done but I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement the spinners in it so I can still have an onClickListener for each and then save the result from each spinner.

I've been trying to find out how but keep hitting dead ends. Any help is appreciated thanks

Here's my main xml for the activity (called activity_register_part2)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="maxbleggi.afstudentplanner.RegisterPart_2Activity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar">
        </include>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/theListView">
            </ListView>

            <com.rey.material.widget.Button
                android:id="@+id/button_register_classes"
                style="@style/RaiseButtonRippleStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:text="@string/button_register_classes"
                android:onClick="onRegisterClassesButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my row layout for the list view (called activity_register_part2_row_layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/period_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"/>

   <com.rey.material.widget.Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_period"
        style="@style/Material.Widget.Spinner"
        app:rd_style="@style/Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave"
        app:spn_arrowColor="#0D47A1"
        app:spn_dividerColor="#0D47A1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Here's my custom array adapter. This is the part where I start getting confused and I don't know how to implement the spinner and text view.

```
package maxbleggi.afstudentplanner;


import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class RegisterPart2Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

    public RegisterPart2Adapter(Context context, String[] resource)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_register_part2_row_layout, resource);
    }
}
```

Finally, here's RegisterPart_2Activity.java

```
    package maxbleggi.afstudentplanner;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import com.rey.material.widget.Spinner;


public class RegisterPart_2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    // initialize the spinners
    private Spinner spinnerPeriod_1;
    private Spinner spinnerPeriod_2;
    private Spinner spinnerPeriod_3;
    private Spinner spinnerPeriod_4;
    private Spinner spinnerPeriod_5;
    private Spinner spinnerPeriod_6;
    private Spinner spinnerPeriod_7;

    // initialize bool to hold whether a class was selected for every period
    private boolean[] isClassSelected = new boolean[10];

    // initialize strings holding the class selected for each period
    private String[] ClassSelected_Period = new String[10];

    /*
    * on creation of activity
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_part_2);

        // toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar;

        // initialise and set toolbar as actionbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // find spinner in view

        // THIS DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE BECAUSE I DON'T HAVE 7 DIFFERENT
        // SPINNERS ONLY ONE THAT IS RECYCLED FOR EACH LIST ITEM
        spinnerPeriod_1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_period_1);
        spinnerPeriod_2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_period_2);
        spinnerPeriod_3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_period_3);
        spinnerPeriod_4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_period_4);
        spinnerPeriod_5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_period_5);
        spinnerPeriod_6 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_period_6);
        spinnerPeriod_7 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_period_7);

        // fill all the spinners with the unit options
        addItemsToSpinner();

        // add listener to the Spinner
        addListenerToSpinner(spinnerPeriod_1, 0);
        addListenerToSpinner(spinnerPeriod_2, 1);
        addListenerToSpinner(spinnerPeriod_3, 2);
        addListenerToSpinner(spinnerPeriod_4, 3);
        addListenerToSpinner(spinnerPeriod_5, 4);
        addListenerToSpinner(spinnerPeriod_6, 5);
        addListenerToSpinner(spinnerPeriod_7, 6);
    }

    public void onSpinner1Clicked(View view)
    {
        ClassSelected_Period[0] = spinnerPeriod_1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    /*
    * adds items to spinners
     */
    public void addItemsToSpinner()
    {
        // create adapter to hold array from class_periods.xml
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerPeriodAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                (this, R.array.class_periods, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerPeriod_7Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                (this,R.array.class_periods, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        spinnerPeriodAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerPeriod_7Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinnerPeriod_1.setAdapter(spinnerPeriodAdapter);
        spinnerPeriod_2.setAdapter(spinnerPeriodAdapter);
        spinnerPeriod_3.setAdapter(spinnerPeriodAdapter);
        spinnerPeriod_4.setAdapter(spinnerPeriodAdapter);
        spinnerPeriod_5.setAdapter(spinnerPeriodAdapter);
        spinnerPeriod_6.setAdapter(spinnerPeriodAdapter);
        spinnerPeriod_7.setAdapter(spinnerPeriod_7Adapter);
    }

    /*
    * adds listener for click to spinner
    */
    public  void addListenerToSpinner(Spinner spinner, final int Period)
    {
        // listener for spinner
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(Spinner parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                // get the item selected in the Spinner
                ClassSelected_Period[Period] = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();

                // a period was selected
                isClassSelected[Period] = true;
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(Spinner parent)
            {
                // a period was not selected
                isClassSelected[Period] = false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
    * when the register classes button is clicked
     */
    public void onRegisterClassesButton(View view)
    {
        // make sure a class was selected for every period
        if (areAllClassesPicked(isClassSelected))
        {
            // get current user
            ParseObject studentClasses = new ParseObject("StudentClasses");

            // register their periods into database
            studentClasses.put("student_id", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
            studentClasses.put("first_period", ClassSelected_Period[0]);
            studentClasses.put("second_period", ClassSelected_Period[1]);
            studentClasses.put("third_period", ClassSelected_Period[2]);
            studentClasses.put("fourth_period", ClassSelected_Period[3]);
            studentClasses.put("fifth_period", ClassSelected_Period[4]);
            studentClasses.put("sixth_period", ClassSelected_Period[5]);
            studentClasses.put("seventh_period", ClassSelected_Period[6]);

            // save the information into database
            studentClasses.saveInBackground();

            // navigate user home
            navigateToHome();
        }
        else
        {
            // user did not fill in needed fields
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterPart_2Activity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Please make sure you select at least one class.")
                    .setTitle("Oops!")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }

    }

    /*
    * checks if all classes were selected
     */
    public boolean areAllClassesPicked(boolean[] array)
    {
        boolean aPeriodWasSelected = false;

        // iterate over every period looking to check if one wasn't picked
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            // if at least one period was not picked
            if (!array[i])
            {
                // fill that unselected period with nothing as the period
                ClassSelected_Period[i] = "Nothing";
            }
            else
            {
                aPeriodWasSelected = true;
            }
        }

        // all periods were picked
        return aPeriodWasSelected;
    }

    /*
    * navigate user home
    */
    private void navigateToHome()
    {
        // let's go to the MainActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterPart_2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

It worked for when I had seven different spinners that I could use but I don't know how to implement it so I can still extract the choice from each spinner.